# Android Structural Find & Replace XML

Tags: android, regex, xml

I'm trying to find instances in my resources where View contains background="@+id/play_bubble" and replace the View with custom view Bubble.

So the current `View` looks like this:

```
<View
    android:id="@+id/obstacle3"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/obstacle_width"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/obstacle_width"
    android:background="@drawable/play_bubble"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_above="@id/obstacle2" />
```

I want it to find all View objects that contain a certain background, regardless of the other attributes. I'm not getting any results though.

My end result after replace should look like this:

```
<Bubble
    android:id="@+id/obstacle3"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/obstacle_width"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/obstacle_width"
    android:background="@drawable/play_bubble"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_above="@id/obstacle2" />
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Edit:

So here's the interface I'm dealing with. I'm not familiar with regex at all, so I'm not sure if I'm inputting things correctly, but it's not returning any results.
[Find/Replace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P8rl0.png)

Comment: What about an xml parser?

Comment: What about using an xml parser?

Comment: This is just a one time search and replace. I'm literally just trying to replace View with Bubble where the background="@id/play_bubble"

Comment: and ignore all other attributes.

Answer (score 2):

Since you mention simple find/replace, this regex should do it.

Find:  `<View(\s+[^>]*?)background="@\+id/play_bubble"([^>]*?/>)`
Replace: `<Bubble$1background="something_new"$2`

Formatted:

```
 <View
 (                                  # (1 start)
      \s+ 
      [^>]*? 
 )                                  # (1 end)
 background="@\+id/play_bubble"
 (                                  # (2 start)
      [^>]*? 
      />
 )                                  # (2 end)
```

Comment: The breakdown is nice, but I personally have no idea what this is or how I would apply it. Is it XPath? Is some sort of XSLT?

Comment: @cricket_007 I don't want to sound like a broken record, but how do you actually use it? I promise I'm not trying to be difficult. I just still don't get it from the answer you've written.

Comment: @Mike, you have to know what Regular Expressions are in order to use it.

Comment: @sin So, I know regular expressions, and I agree that this answer is on the right track. My point is that it's not a complete answer. I'd just like to see the proof that this actually works, and in what context (Java, Python, Bash, etc.)

Comment: @Mike  - You'll get no code from me Mile. Regex is %95 universal, the language you choose is up to you. I use [this](http://www.regexformat.com) to make and test the regex. But you can use anything you want. SO is not really the place to fish for code, you'll find %95 of the regex answers here are free of language specific's unless the request is for its functions. It's already assumed the asker has knowledge of the language they are using.

Comment: @Mike - Pretty sure Android Studio / IntelliJ has a regex find replace feature.

Comment: @sin Alright, fair enough. I've changed my downvote to an upvote then, since you did a great job of explaining the regular expression. 

Thanks for taking the time to explain the situation. I'm new, and in most of answers I've given thus far, I assumed a code snippet was mandatory.

Comment: @cricket_007 Yeah, I typically use http://www.regexpal.com/. There's also several plugins for regex in Eclipse. All gems.